# Is it meaningful to call a Menu-related event a "callback function"?

Tags: android, events, callback

I'm going through the android notepad tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html

In Notepadv2, Step 5, it says:

> onListItemClick() is a callback method that we'll override.

I'm a bit new to the concept of callbacks, but from researching, my understanding is that a callback is code you provide in one process that's executed when another process reaches a certain result. What makes this particular event a callback, and not other events?

Is this a callback because it's only called when the user does something (in this case, click on a list item)? But if that's so, can't any event be considered a callback in that it's only called when something outside of itself happens? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> my understanding is that a callback is code you provide in one process that's executed when another process reaches a certain result

Not exactly.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) describes a callback as "a reference to executable code, or a piece of executable code, that is passed as an argument to other code". That's probably the best use of the term. In this case, since Java operations come in the form of methods, a "callback method" is a method that will be invoked as a result of a callback.

> Is this a callback because it's only called when the user does something (in this case, click on a list item)?

Not exactly.

It is a callback method because other pieces of the Android framework are detecting an event (in this case, the user tapping on an item in a list) and are calling the `onListItemClick()` callback method to give you control.

> But if that's so, can't any event be considered a callback in that it's only called when something outside of itself happens?

Usually, "callback" is reserved for cases where there's a clearly defined opaque boundary between the module detecting the event and the module implementing the callback to process the event. In this case, you did not write the Android operating system, and so `onListItemClick()` is a callback into your own code that the OS will call to let you process list item clicks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand this. The thing I still don't get is - if a requirement of a callback is that a piece of code or a reference to code is passed, where am I passing that code in this case? I don't have to tell the other code to call that method, it does it as the result of an event. Does it satisfy the requirements to be a callback just because it's called from a module I didn't write myself, even though I don't have to pass that method to other code?

Comment: Looking at the sample code some more, it includes this

`startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);`

I suppose that constant is the "reference to code" that is being passed? In that, when the external code does eventually call back, it will pass the value of that constant back to `onActivityResult()` (which I write)  so I know how to interpret its call to my function?

The function that it actually calls back is `onActivityResult()`. Wouldn't this make THAT the callback? Or is this just a matter of semantics?

Comment: "Does it satisfy the requirements to be a callback just because it's called from a module I didn't write myself, even though I don't have to pass that method to other code?" -- yes. In object-oriented programming, it's called "inheritance". "I suppose that constant is the "reference to code" that is being passed?" -- no. "it will pass the value of that constant back...so I know how to interpret its call to my function?" -- yes. "Or is this just a matter of semantics?" -- you are welcome to write your own Android docs if you don't like the ones that are there.

Answer (score 1):

CommonsWare answer is far more complete, but I think I can simplify the explanation a little.

A *callback* is something that *gets called back*. Conceptually, you declare that you're interested in a particular event (e.g. a button click, when a certain task finishes, an amount of time went by, etc.) and instruct your code to *call you back* when it occurs.

It's just like picking up the phone and telling someone "call me back when you're ready". The callback won't take the form of a phone call, but of a function call.

You call a function and hand it a *callback*, and that function *calls back your callback* when appropiate.